# code coverage breaks while running ng test

Tags: angular, jasmine, code-coverage, karma-runner

We have around 5000 odd spec files, when we run code coverage using the following command:
node --max_old_space_size=10240 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng test --code-coverage=true
the code coverage suddenly gives unknown 0% in the middle of running test suites - no error

Any advice how to run code coverage for a giant code base

tried running in batches but code coverage does not give correct report